# PLUpload C# Direct To S3 Working Sample

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, plupload

.net plupload amazon s3 SOS

The new PLUpload has a PHP sample for direct upload to Amazon S3. The claim is it is "easily" translatable to other platforms.

However "easy" is a relative term and unfortunately I am currently stumped. I have never touched PHP before and I would love to see any working sample where someone has pulled this off either in VB.NET or C# (C# preferably).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I created a sample MVC3 app and put it on Github which in part was based on Cary's work found in a forum post.

Details on my blog:
http://blog.cdeutsch.com/2011/07/aspnet-mvc3-app-using-plupload-to.html

Github:
https://github.com/crdeutsch/MVC3PluploadToAmazonS3